# VS2017 ASP .NET Core Error when adding a Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When I right click on a folder Add->View to add a Razor View:

[image: Add View Dialog]

I get the following error:

`No executable found matching the command dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

[image: Error]

From initial searches online, I've not found a solution.  I've had this working on some projects - but cannot figure how to resolve this!  I've reinstalled VS2017 but the problem still exists.

I suspect it is something in the project.  I've tried readding the code generation related packages but still the problem exists.

Here is my csproj Package and Tool references:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
        <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="3.3.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2017.1.223" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

I have the same issue adding `Controllers` using right-click Add->Controller too, so this is not restricted to Razor Views.

This does work from context menu Add->New Item...->MVC View Page or Add->New Item...->MVC Controller Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same thing happen again tonight.

I added a `Razor View` to my pretty much empty ASP NET Core Application.  I was prompted to select an option to add minimal dependencies or full dependencies to the project.

I opted for minimal dependencies then a ScaffoldingReadMe.txt appeared.  It read:

ASP.NET MVC core dependencies have been added to the project.
However you may still need to do make changes to your project.

```
1. Add Scaffolding CLI tool to the project:

<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I tried adding the view via scaffolding and it failed as before.  However, taking on board what the text file said, adding the above XML to the csproj file worked - the view was scaffolded successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Currenly I'm targeting netcoreapp 1.1 and it works for me. After I paste your csproj vs17 automatically wants to install WPF and desktop stuffs which pretty bad actually. Could you try my csproj is it works for you? I'm investigation maybe I can found something :)

Update: Easiest way to find out tweet to David Kean ( https://twitter.com/davkean ). He will propably know whats the problem and when will they fix it.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">   
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\A\Controllers\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I did try this out but still kept getting the same error.  I've since just reinstalled my windows 10 and vs2017 so hopefully this will be ok for new projects.  I've scrapped the solution and generated new .net core projects across the board.  I've still to migrate the web project where the problem was.