# Using ASP NET Core MVC 6 Anchor Tag Helper to an Area Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an `Area` named Projects I am trying to navigate to.  This area has two `Controller`s named Project and Dashboard, each with an Index action.

```
[Authorize]
[Area("Projects")]
public class ProjectController : Controller
{
    ...
}

[Authorize]
[Area("Projects")]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

I have the following routes defined in Startup.cs.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Projects",
        template: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

    ...
});
```

When I type the url "http://localhost:1234:Projects/Dashboard" to the Dashboard it works - the view is displayed.  However, having the following tag helper defined in this view to the Project controller, I get the url `http://localhost:1234/Project?area=Projects` with a 404 not found:

```
<a asp-area="Projects" asp-controller="Project" asp-action="Index">
    <span>Goto Project</span>
</a>
```

The url needs to be http://localhost:1234/Projects/Project.  If I enter that in the browser address bar then it shows the Projects Index View.  I am assuming my routes are configured correctly.

I've tried asp-area="Projects" and omitting asp-area tags also.  I've trawled through the [area docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas) and [routing docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) multiple times to no avail.

I am targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2.  Here is the csproj areas of interest:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="3.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2017.1.223" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I've created a folder named Areas at the root level of the project. Ie:

```
ACMEMVCWebApp\Areas\Projects
ACMEMVCWebApp\Areas\Projects\Controllers
ACMEMVCWebApp\Areas\Projects\Views
```

How can I navigate from Dashboard to Project using the Anchor Tag Helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing):

`Routes in the route collection are ordered, and will be processed in the order they are added. So in this example, the blog route will be tried before the default route.`

So this needs to be areas first before default route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Projects",
        template: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

}
```

Given that, I still find it odd that typing the url in directly worked.  The problem was in the Tag Helpers.

Comment: Hmm somehow the url generation ( Generator.GenerateActionLink ) not cares about the order or use it differently. I worth to file an issue to MVC repo to get the proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried in a new application and it works fine.

Which version of .Net Core are you using?

I just check the [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs) and it should be fine. Maybe some package mismatch?

So here is my example configuration. I put area route to the top like this:

[image: Route]

[image: Controller]

[image: View]

[image: Generated URL]

Comment: Interesting - I will update question.  I also have the issue that I cannot add a controller/view using the following technique in this project - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43291464/vs2017-asp-net-core-error-when-adding-a-razor-view

Comment: A game of spot the difference between your code and mine.  It would appear to be the order of the routes.  Add the areas first - before the default route.

Answer (score 1):

I too have this problem with generating the correct url to a controller action within an area.  I have found the fix that may be of interest to some with the same issue.

The order of the routes was the issue with creating the correct url to the action.  In my case I was generating the action for a form and was moving some code from MVC 5 to MVC Core 2.0.  The original code used a html helper like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

And produced the following correct markup:

```
<form action="/Admin/Role/Create?_=1505204033132" method="post">
```

I then updated the code to use the tag helper as I quite like the syntax.  I changed the above to:

```
<form asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Role" asp-action="Create" method="post">
```

This did not create the correct url.  The code it produced looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/Role/Create?area=Admin">
```

Using this url gives the expected 404 response.

Changing the order of the routes around, in startup.cs, so that the area route was first fixed the issue and the url is now correct.

I have no idea why this is so and was very surprised to find that the routing had any control over the generation of the url.  This certainly has the ability to catch me out again as i would have thought that the two were separate entities and that the routing was only used when a request was made - seems that is not a correct assumption.

Gordon